# Node: Node-sass not contain "vendor" file on npm install => "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '...\node-sass\vendor' "

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-modules, node-sass

I have a problem with "node-sass". 
After npm install, in node-modules, node-sass not contain "vendor" file.
All good on "npm install", but when I tried to run my project an error is throwing: 
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.\node-sass\vendor'`

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    ...
  }
```

- Node version : v10.16
- Npm version : v6.9

I've tried:

```
npm i
npm rebuid node-sass
```

```
npm i
npm rebuid node-sass--force
```

```
Remove "node_modules"
npm i
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i node-sass@4.9
```

```
Remove "node_modules"
npm i
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i node-sass@latest
```

```
Remove "node_modules"
npm cache clean --force
npm i
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

```
Remove "node_modules"
npm i
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i node-sass
npm rebuild node-sass--force
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

you can fix it by adding the node saas binding manually in the \node-sass\vendor folder:

1. Download the node saas from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases
2. create a folder in **node_modules\node-sass\vendor**  and rename it (OS-Architecture): for exemple **win32-x64-64** for windows32
3. put the downloaded file in this floder
4. rename the file **binding.node**